# Select a row of the table with desired value, when a column's value which is not in the table is selected in where clause in keyword?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a table with one of the columns as ID. I have a set of values which I give in the where clause to compare the 'ID' column using 'in' keyword. I want to select the row if the value in that set of values has a record in the table. If not, the value that is not in the table has to be selected along with empty values other columns.

For example:
There is a table with columns ID & Animal. It has 8 records.

[The table with all records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfQDW.png)

If I run the query:

```
SELECT ID, Animal from #Temp1 where ID in (4,8)
```

it will return the following result.

[The table result filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKlUk.png)

But, if I run the query:

```
SELECT ID, Animal from #Temp1 where ID in (4,8,12)
```

it should return the following result.

[The table result with desired values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqr3R.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: The use of IN will not be useful here. You need to **outer join** your table to the desired set of ID values to force the inclusion of those IDs that do not exist in your actual table. Think about that and give it a try. And please - no more images as data, especially small blurry ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` in concert with `string_split()` instead

```
Select ID = A.value
      ,Animal = coalesce(B.Animal,'ID Not Found') 
 From string_split('4,8,12',',') A
 Left Join YourTable B on A.value=B.ID
```

**Results**

```
ID  Animal
4   Donkey
8   Hampster
12  ID Not Found
```

If by chance string_split() is not available

```
Select ID = A.value
      ,Animal = coalesce(B.Animal,'ID Not Found') 
 From (values (4)
             ,(8)
             ,(12)
      ) A(value)
 Left Join YourTable B on A.value=B.ID
```

Comment: If that ID column is not an integer and if it has some 10 digit number as value, then how can the query be formed?
E.g., If possible value of 'ID' column is something like this '0000390110'

Comment: @VaishnaviSrinivas Int or String ... It will still work.   for example  string_split('00004,00008,00012',',') A  or the second approach would be values ('00004')

Comment: I can't even begin to imagine why you would use `STRING_SPLIT` here, rather than `VALUES` or a Table Valued Parameter

Comment: @Charlieface I IMAGINED  the IDs were going to change from time-to-time and OP was looking for a flexible solution, so that would exclude the VALUE approach.  I find TVP's are cumbersome.